# c++: How to find the two peaks of the histogram (already wrapped into array of int)?

Tags: c++, arrays, histogram

there is an array

```
int gist [256] = {/ * e.g., 34, 54, 0, 87, 34, 65, 0, 98, and so on. * /};
```

It is a histogram of one of the channels (let it be B) image, which monochrome object one color lies on the plain background of a different color. Needs to find two peaks, the first of which was supposed to belong to the background, and the second, respectively - the object. Please suggest an algorithm, but better - code.

I've looked, there an array of highly rarefied group of 2-4 values ​​occur in 20-30 empty elements. In general, the way it should be, I think.

Comment: In order to do your homework, first shows us what you have tried so far

Comment: Aren't you just looking for the two greatest values in your array? Write an algorithm to get the greatest value in your array, and then modify it to get the two greatest values

Comment: Does the entire array represent just the background, or just the object, or both mixed together somehow? To search an array for its highest value, you can use [`std::max_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), eg: `int *highest = std::max_element(gist, gist+256);`

Comment: No, i need to find two areals with picks in a rarefied mass, two biggest values i can find ind by myself.

Comment: @Nicolazz92: I have no idea what you just said. Are you trying to find the highest 1-2 values that appear within surrounding 0 values?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XsAyB.png whatch this, like these two peaks.

Comment: You need to find the two blip blops in the blob durp...

Comment: @Nicolazz92: That did not answer my question. You have an array of int values.  How does the array you showed correlate to the image you just showed? What EXACTLY are you looking for in the array?

Comment: Remy, I guess so... And yes, object and backdround are mixed.

Comment: @Nicolazz92 - I suppose you will have to do some averaging of the last n number of values and mark where the average is the highest.

Comment: @Remy, give me a minute.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau , I work with OpenCV. I got an image with a monohrome object on monohrome background, which i split on three channels: b,g and r(not rgb, but bgr), every channel I normalized. And in every channel I have to find two picks to find an object. But, becouse of I normalized channels(equalizeHist), massives of histogramms rarefied. Here is a code, if you want https://yadi.sk/d/YI5rFwpnfiGnJ